# HTML5 Drag and Drop Without Changing the Markup

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I imagine that the answer to this question is no, but just in case I'm going to ask it anyway.

I want to use know if it is possible to use html5 drag and drop functionality **without** adding markup to the html (i.e., without adding draggable="true".

The reason I'm asking is because I want to use this within TinyMCE but I do NOT want to publish to the front end dragabble="true". I only want the drag and drop to function in the backend.

Any ideas?

P.S.  I imagine I could see if there is a filter within TinyMCE for when the content actually gets published to the front end, but I would first prefer to see if it is possible to do this without a filter.

Answer (score 0):

These things are draggable by default (ie. without any kind of attribute):

- Links
- Images
- Selections

If you can make everything you want to be draggable be one of those things then you're OK, you just have to handle the events in the normal way.  The easiest ways I can think of are:

- Absolutely positioned images as 'drag proxies' (if they're absolutely positioned then they'll be out of the document flow)
- Automatically select text on mouseover

However, I think it would be far more simple to add and remove the `draggable` attributes dynamically, eg. with jQuery (perhaps in the save event of TinyMCE):

```
$('#editor *').removeAttr('draggable');
```